# Maxium subset of elements in array within capacity

Tags: algorithm

> An unsorted array is filled with random, positive integers. What is the
>   maximum subset of elements where the total does not exceed the capacity C?
>   ie: Array [1, 5, 3, 6, 3, 2] where C = 9 | Answer: {1, 2, 3, 3}
>
> **Constraint:** O(n) time complexity
>   *Hint:* Prune & Search and QuickSelect

I've spent quite awhile thinking of how to solve this problem, but the constraint is making this extremely difficult. My assumption is that the array doesn't need to be fully sorted as the hint recommends a combination of prune & search and QuickSelect. QuickSelect is fairly straightforward to find in constant time (using the [median method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Median_selection_as_pivot_strategy)), but I'm not sure how the combination of the two will help to find the answer.

Comment: In your given example, Array [1, 5, 3, 6, 3, 2] where C = 8 | Answer: {1, 2, 3, 3}, here (1+2+3+3) > C. Is your example is correct? or by total you mean something else?

Comment: Whoops, small typo. Fixed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question assumes that you need to separate smaller elements until their sum reaches `C`.

Choose pivot (any method).
Perform partition relative to pivot.
Calculate sum of the left part.
If it is too small `(Sum < C)`, solve the same problem for the right part **and value** `C'=C-Sum` recursively
If Sum is too large `Sum > C`, solve the same problem for the left part.

This is modification of [QuickSelect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect)

For good partition scheme you'll have about `n + n/2 + n/4 + n/8... +1 = 2*n = O(n)` operations of summation (plus partition cost, inherent for Quickselect)

Comment: Wouldn't there be an issue if the sum of the left/right side = the capacity C as the question is asking for maximum number of elements that doesn't exceed C (rather than find any combination of elements where the sum = C)?

Comment: I believe that `sum=C` for the left part is the perfect solution - left part contains smaller elements, so their number is the largest possible for given sum